# "booster.filters.BootstrapFilter" is invalid while using yiibooster in controller

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

Hi I want to use yiibooster in my yii project and I have downloaded yiibooster version 4.0.1.
I have changed in config/main.php before return array

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('booster', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/yiibooster');
```

In component section added

```
  'booster' => array(
    'class' => 'booster.components.Booster',
  ),
```

and in controller added

```
array('booster.filters.BootstrapFilter - delete'),
```

In the view file

```
$this->widget(
  'booster.widgets.TbSelect2', array(
    'asDropDownList' => false,
    'name' => 'clevertech',
    'options' => array(
        'tags' => array('clever', 'is', 'better', 'clevertech'),
        'placeholder' => 'type clever, or is, or just type!',
        'width' => '40%',
        'tokenSeparators' => array(',', ' '),
      )
   )
);
```

There is an error showing

> Alias "booster.filters.BootstrapFilter" is invalid. Make sure it
>   points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.

Is there any issue with bootster filter in controller section?What I have missed?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path is not correct. Remove the

`Yii::setPathOfAlias('booster', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/yiibooster');`

It should be something like that:

`'booster' => Array(
    'class' => 'ext.yiibooster.components.Booster',
),`